# How do I do data validation for multiple emails?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I need to type multiple emails separated by commas, They have to be data validated in excel or google sheets.

I have tried with `=ISEMAIL(G)` and `=REGEXMATCH(g,"^((([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))(\s*,\s*|\s*$))*$")`

but the former doesn't give error but it cant handle multiple ids,
the later says its invalid

Any ways, this can be achieved?

Comment: what are we supposed understand from your regex ? you better give some examples, some valid emails , some invalid emails, and also conditions that must be followed to mark an email as valid !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=ArrayFormula(ISEMAIL(SPLIT(A1,",")))`

[image]

Comment: This takes invalid too in data validation "a@gmail.com,b" is also valid

Comment: the formula gives `true` for "a@gmail.com" and `false` for "b". If you want to check all, use `=AND(ArrayFormula(ISEMAIL(SPLIT(A1,","))))`

Comment: Thank you very much